# Android - Any third party tool for designing & generating XML?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

Is there any third party tool in which we can design layouts for android and then it generates their xml files accordingly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is something called [DroidDraw](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Programming/Coding-languages-Compilers/DroidDraw.shtml) using which you can generate xml file easily. Its a User Interface(UI) designer/editor. You need to drag and drop widgets into editor then it will generate respective xml code. Hope its helpful.

Comment: Its nice, but its not mature enough for customizing tab widgets.

Comment: hmmm yeah... its useful for simple tasks. Hope they will upgrade it to do something complex

Answer (score 3):

[IntelliJ IDEA 12](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/index.html) has a graphical editor for the layouts, that on the fly also generates XML. The same applies the other way around. The community edition of IntelliJ IDEA is free and open source.

Answer (score 0):

You can use external editors. But I recommend working with XML itself because you get a much greater degree of control.

As a simplified example, you might use a visual layout editor to drag a text box to a size that looks good. But it might only look good for the particular screen size and resolution that you're using to test it. Instead, if you use an xml property like "wrap-content", then your text box will automatically readjust it's size to enclose the text inside it and this will happen reliably in all screen sizes/resolutions.

Of course, you'll still have to fine-tune and tweak your layouts for the screen sizes and resolutions you plan to target with your app, but just for the fine-grain control and accuracy you get, using xml directly is highly recommended in my opinion.

It's not that difficult once you get the hang of it either :-)